# How to compare two CSV's by first column and see if there are any duplicates using Python not pandas

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to read two CSV files and compare the first column (ID) and see if there are duplicates. If they are duplicates I have to tell the user which ID's are duplicates and only copy the unique ID's values into the first csv.

`first csv = transactions_ledgers.csv` (contains column headers) and has some values stored in it. Column[0] is ID.

`second csv = transactions_q1.csv` (no column headers) the values on column[0] are ID's

So I need to read the second CSV to see if there are duplicates on the first CSV. If there are, I need to print the ids that are duplicated and only append the unique ids from csv 2 to csv 1.

Unfortunately, I can not use Pandas; it has to be using Python.

````
#Using set
with open('transactions_q1.csv') as check_file:
#header = next(check_file)
check_set = set([row.split(',')[0].strip().upper() for row in check_file])
with open('transactions_q2.csv', 'r') as in_file, open('unique_transaction_ledgers.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    for line in in_file:
        if line.split(',')[0].strip().upper() in check_set:
            out_file.write(line)```
# Second Option
with open('transaction_ledger.csv','r') as file:
    read = csv.reader(file)
    header=next(file)
    for line in read:
        ids=line[0]
with open('transactions_q2.csv','r') as file:
    read = csv.reader(file)
    header=next(file)
    for line in read:
        ids2=line[0]
if ids == ids2:
    print("oh no duplicates")
````

Here is the function I am trying to incorporate @craigb answer to my initial question.

The code that I am sharing is a function that ultimately does the following:

1. Ask the user what transaction they want to perform: stats or import (stats is working). When they chose import two several things needed to happen:
2. Check if the file the user is trying to import exists if it doesn't then tell the user the file doesn't exist and they can try again.
3. If the file does exist read its content to be able to compare the ID column (unique identifier) with the ID column from the transaction_ledgers.csv (the main file where all previous transactions are stored). If the imported CSV contains duplicate transactions then tell the user what transactions IDs are duplicates and only add the unique transactions to the transaction_ledgers.csv and prompt the user with the total unique transactions made or exported into the transactions_ledgers.csv.
4. There are two options a transaction_ledgers.csv already exists (it's created when someone runs the import function or it might not and needs to be created with all the contents of the imported file.
5. Let the user perform as many transactions as they wish

My current code is running but I am facing several inconveniences.

1. The file transaction_ledgers.csv is not keeping the past data and resets. This might be because I am writing and not appending it. But I am unsure of this.
2. When counting the unique transactions if there are duplicate values in the transaction I am getting 0 as a result instead of the total number of transactions that have been made.

Thank you in advance for any guidance provided!

```py
#Create the ImportFunction

#Import dependencies
def ImportFunction():
    #This function is created for the user to be able to import new files into the main file and check for duplicate transactions
    #Set counters, lists and sets that will be used in the code
    ids= set()
    total_rows = 0
    duplicate_lines = []
    duplicate=[]
    
    #First step is to ask the user what file they would like to import
    which_file = input("Which file would you like to import?")
    
    #Using os.path.exists check if the 'main' file transaction_ledgeres.csv exists. if it does set varible to 'yes' if not set variable to 'no'
    if os.path.exists('transaction_ledger.csv'):
        main_file ='yes'
    else:
        main_file = 'no'
     #Created a conditional statement to check if the "user choice" file existis or not
    if os.path.exists(which_file):
        is_file='yes'
    else:
        #Prompt the user the file doesnt exist in this file path
        print(f"This file '{which_file}' does not exist.")
        is_file='no'
    
    #Created a conditional statement if the file does or doesn't exist to perform actions
    if main_file == 'yes':    
        #If true then open the file and perform actions
        if is_file == 'yes':
            #Second step is to load the file into python. 
            with open(which_file,'r') as file:
                user_file = file.read()
            #print(user_file)             
            print("File Imported succesfully, checking for possible duplicate transactions...")    

            #Reading in the transaction_ledger.csv Since its true
            with open('transaction_ledger.csv','r') as file:
                trans_file = csv.reader(file)
                header = next(trans_file) #This will skip the headers on CSV to be able to compare ID in column one and see if there is duplicate values
                #Created loop with the help @craigb anwser on my quesiton on stackover overflow
                for i in trans_file:
                    ids.add(i[0].strip().upper())

            #NEW FILE WITH UNIQUE TRANSACTION CONTENT ONLY NO DUPLICATES with the help @craigb anwser on my quesiton on stackover overflow
            with open(which_file,'r') as file, open('unique_transaction_ledgers.csv', 'w') as out_file,open('duplicated_transaction_ledgers.csv', 'w') as duplicated_file:
                reader = csv.reader(file)
                writer = csv.writer(out_file)
                writer2 = csv.writer(duplicated_file)
                for line in reader:
                    if line[0].strip().upper() in ids:
                        total_rows += 1
                        writer.writerow(line)
                        duplicate.append(line[0])
                print(f"The following transactions have already been recorded: {duplicate} ")
                print(f"Number of current transactions:{total_rows-len(duplicate)}")
                for line in reader:
                    if line[0].strip().upper() not in ids:
                        total_rows += 1
                        duplicate_lines.append(line[0])
                        writer2.writerow(line)
                        
                    print(f"The following transactions have already been recorded: {line} ")
                    print(f"Number of current transactions:{total_rows-len(duplicate_lines)}")# this is always zero in the terminal and it should not be
        #If file doesn't exist set flag to true
        else:
            flag = True
    #If the main file does not exist then create it and perform the actions needed        
    if main_file == 'no':
        
         #Open the user file and read it to be able to append to the new empty file transaction_ledger.csv
        with open(which_file,'r') as old_file:
            reader_obj = csv.reader(old_file) #read the current csv file

            with open('transaction_ledger.csv', 'w') as new_file:
                writer_obj = csv.writer(new_file, delimiter=",",lineterminator = "\n")
                header = ['ID', 'COMPANY NAME', 'DATE', 'AMOUNT', 'STATUS']
                writer_obj.writerow(header)
                for data in reader_obj:
                    total_rows += 1
                    #loop through the read data and write each row in transaction_Ledger.csv
                    writer_obj.writerow(data)
                print("New file created and filled in with imported file data")
                print(f"Number of current transactions:{total_rows}")
         
        
#Create boolean value for while loop name it flag
flag = True

#Created while loop
while flag:
    #Ask the user what action they want to perform. 
    user_selection = input("What would you like to perform (import/statistics) or end the simulation?")
    # Conditional - if they choose stats then call the function statistics
    if user_selection.strip().lower() == 'statistics':
        statistics()
        #Ask user if they want to run another analysis 
        repeat1 = input('Would you like to run any further analyses (yes/no)?' )
        if 'y' in repeat1.strip().lower():
            #ask user what they want to do
            next_step = input("What would you like to perform (import/statistics)?")
            if next_step.lower().strip() == 'statistics':
                #if statistics than run the statistics function
                statistics()
                #keep flag true to loop again if the user wants to 
                flag = True
                
                #If import run the ImportFunction and keep flag true
            elif next_step.lower().strip() == 'import':
                ImportFunction()
                flag = True
       
        #If they don't want to continue then end the simulation and turn flag False        
        else:
            print("Thanks for using this simulation")
            flag = False
        
    #Conditional -  if they choose the import function then call the ImportFunction
    elif user_selection.lower().strip() == 'import':
        ImportFunction()
        #Ask user if they want to run another analysis 
        repeat = input('Would you like to run any further analyses (yes/no)?' )
        if 'y' in repeat.strip().lower():
            flag = True
        else:
            print("Thanks for using this simulation")
            flag = False
    elif 'e' in user_selection[0].lower().strip():
        print("Thanks for using this simulation")
        flag = False
    #If the user inputs an invalid operation then prompt them that the program doesn't perform the action and ask them to try again
    else:
        print("Sorry, this program can only run the following two functions: 1. Import 2. Statistics or you can end the simulation")
        flag = True
'''
```

Comment: Build a `set` or `dict` with all the IDs from the first cvs.  Then check membership in that `set` or `dict` as you loop through the second csv.  We can help with the code if you try something first.

Comment: Are you familiar with the `csv` module? You can use it to read your files, and then use a set as craigb says to implement the logic your are describing.

Comment: Thank you @craigb! I Have tried multiple things I am editing my previous post with the code. If you could please help me figure out what I am missing that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for writing some code.  The first option works as is, although it writes IDs that are common to both files.  Here's the code with that logic reversed - it only writes lines whose IDs are in `transactions_q2.csv` but not in `transactions_q1.csv` (just replace `in` with `not in`):

```py
#Using set
with open('transactions_q1.csv') as check_file:
    check_set = set([row.split(',')[0].strip().upper() for row in check_file])
with open('transactions_q2.csv', 'r') as in_file, open('unique_transaction_ledgers.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    for line in in_file:
        if line.split(',')[0].strip().upper() not in check_set:
            out_file.write(line)
```

Your 2nd option using the `csv` module doesn't gather up the IDs from the first file. Here are some changes that builds a set and checks it like the first option (I removed the `header()` code - put that back in if there are headers; I wanted this to work the same as option #1):

```py
# Second Option
ids = set()
with open('transactions_q1.csv','r') as file:
    read = csv.reader(file)
    for line in read:
        ids.add(line[0].strip().upper())
with open('transactions_q2.csv','r') as file, open('unique_transaction_ledgers.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    for line in reader:
        if line[0].strip().upper() not in ids:
            writer.writerow(line)
```

Your third option isn't complete and it's hard to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked on a smaller scale I haven't been able to implement the counting option when setting up the function. I am updating the initial post to show you the code I have and see if you could point me in the right direction regarding what I might be missing.